# VBA - Hide/unhide row based on hidden/unhidden status of another row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write some VBA code that will unhide an entire row if another specific row is hidden. This macro also hides a range of rows based on the value in a specific column. This aspect works fine - I have reliable code. I can't get the first function I described to work. Should be easy to do, just don't know the syntax. This subroutine should execute upon opening the workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim targ As Range
Dim msg As Range

targ = "DETAILS!B6"
msg = "DETAILS!B42"

msg.EntireRow.Hidden = True


With Range("DETAILS!B6:B40")
        .EntireRow.Hidden = False

        For Each cell In Range("DETAILS!B6:B40")
        Select Case cell.Value

        Case Is = 0
        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True

        End Select
        Next cell
End With


If targ.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
    msg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Where have you placed that code? It should be in the private module of the Workbook Object (ThisWorkbook).  That's your issue yeah, the code works, it's just not firing on open?

Comment: Yes, it is the the `ThisWorkbook` object. When I open the workbook, I get the following error: `Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set`. When I hit 'Debug', the line that is highlighted is `targ="DETAILS!B6"`. Maybe it is the value I'm assigning to the `targ` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you can call range objects like this : `Range("DETAILS!B6:B40")`

In vba it is better accepted to call it like this: `Sheets("DETAILS").Range("B6:B40")`

I fixed a few more syntax errors:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim targ As Range
Dim msg As Range

Set targ = Sheets("DETAILS").Range("B6")
Set msg = Sheets("DETAILS").Range("B42")

msg.EntireRow.Hidden = True


With Sheets("DETAILS").Range("B6:B40")
        .EntireRow.Hidden = False
End With

For Each cell In Sheets("DETAILS").Range("B6:B40")
    Select Case cell.Value
        Case 0
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End Select
Next cell



If targ.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
    msg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the variables like below

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim targ As Range
Dim msg As Range

Set targ = "DETAILS!B6"
Set msg = "DETAILS!B42"

msg.EntireRow.Hidden = True


With Range("DETAILS!B6:B40")
    .EntireRow.Hidden = False

    For Each cell In Range("DETAILS!B6:B40")
    Select Case cell.Value

    Case Is = 0
    cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End Select
    Next cell
End With


If targ.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
    msg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh! Just put `Set` before `targ` and `msg` since they're a `Range`.  When declaring ranges, you have to have `Set`, i.e. `Set myRng = Range("A1:A10")`.

You *might* need to do `Set targ = Range("Details!B6")` if just `Set Targ = "DetailsB6"` doesn't work.

On second thought, I don't think `Set Targ = "Details!B6"` will work if you are `Dim Targ as Range`. You're dim'ing as a Range, but are declaring it as like a string.  You need this to be a Range, to use it like `targ.EntireRow.Hidden`, etc.